# Change EXIF and/or Creation date based on folder name

Tags: metadata, batch, exiftool, date

I have lots of photos with non-existent exif dates where the write date is not correct. The original dates disappeared during a hard drive replacement. But they are in folders with the correct date.

Example: folder name "2003-01-22" contains photos with writing date 2017-05-20.

I want to be able to change / add exif and write the date based on the folder name.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming there are **no** other numbers in the directory path, you could use
`exiftool "-AllDates<$Directory 00:00:00" /path/to/files`

That would set the EXIF timestamps to midnight on the date in the filepath.

If there are other numbers in the directory path, then a complex command would have to be used.  Assuming the date is **exactly** as you posted
`exiftool "-AllDates<${Directory;m/(\d{4}-\d\d-\d\d)/;$_=$1} 00:00:00" /path/to/files`

These commands cannot be run from that directory, i.e. using a dot to indicate the directory.  They must be run from above that directory using the [`-r` (`-recurse`)](https://ExifTool.org/exiftool_pod.html#r-.--recurse) option or must include the date as part of the indicated path, e.g. `/path/to/2003-01-22/`.

This command also does not affect the file system time stamps. To set those as well, duplicate the center part but replace `AllDates` with `FileModifyDate` or `FileCreateDate`.

This command will overwrite any existing timestamps, so make sure you're processing the correct files (see the [`-wm` (`-writemode`) option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#wm-MODE--writeMode) for ways to alter this). This command creates backup files.  Add [`-overwrite_original`](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#overwrite_original) to suppress the creation of backup files. If this command is run under Unix/Mac, reverse any double/single quotes to avoid bash interpretation.